# Jpa does not update data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I have a method in `Controller`:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/children", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void createChild(@RequestBody CreateChildRequestDTO childDTO) {
        Long guardianId = Long.parseLong(childDTO.getGuardianId());
        Child child = childDTO.getChild();
        Guardian guardian = guardianService.findById(guardianId).get();
        boolean isExist = childService.isExist(child.getChildFullName(),
                child.getPassword(),
                child.getPhoneNumber());
        if (isExist) {
            child = childService.findChildByNameAndPass(child.getChildFullName(), child.getPassword());
            guardian.addChild(child);
        }
        else {
            guardian.addChild(child);
            childService.createChild(child);
        }
    }
```

And also I have created a many-to-many relationship in `Guradian` class:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "guardian_child", schema = "cheer",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "guardianid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "childid"))
private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
```

When I run the code and execute line `guardian.addChild(child)` child is added to guardian's list, but not created a new record in table. How to fix it? Commit change in objects relation?

Comment: You never save the changes

Comment: block `else` is working. And new record adds to guardian_child table

Comment: and i don't understand how is it possible?

Comment: Well without the code for `childService.createChild(child);` I am not sure how you expect that to be answered. I would guess because childService saves the child??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Jens suggested in the comment, you're never saving changes to the database.

There are two ways you can resolve this issue:

1. You can run the code within a transaction, then hibernate will take care of dirty-checking and commit all the changes to the parent to the database.
2. You can save `guardian` by calling something like that at the end of the method:

   ```
   guardianService.save(guardian);
   ```

Comment: @Krazim00da the fact that the code is working and entities have relationships, doesn't mean they are saved to the database

Comment: i checked the records in db...and after `else` there is new record.

Comment: @Krazim00da then what is your problem?

Comment: identical code in `if(true)` isn't working. and new record is not added

Comment: how do i must realise save method?